# How to get cookie value using URL?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

How to send Cookies as URL parameter from one site to another site  ..

I want code like

```
www.TestApplication.com?cookieValue=values
```

Comment: When appropriate cookies are sent automatically by the browser in a request-header, you need to explain specifically what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: For same domain it is ok.. But for different domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot share cookies across sites, I'm afraid. This is basic security feature. Otherwise malicious websites could steal your banking session cookies.

Comment: Ok. But for session hijacking hackers using this method for getting the session cookie details..

Comment: you mean, you want to get own cookies and then make XHR to another site? Then which part is not clear: how to retrieve a cookie, or how to make an XHR?

Comment: how to retrieve a cookie..I don't know more about XHR.. I want cookies of another site

Comment: You cannot get cookies from another site; you can only give own cookies to another site. document.cookie contains semicolon-separated list of name=vale of the cookies of your own page; you can use that to pass to another site using XHR.